# Is there a thing as a "Negative Dimensional Space"?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, dimension-theory-algebra

I am wondering if there is a pure mathematical, abstract, extension of the Euclidean space for *negative* *dimensions*. Do you know any studies in topology, regarding this matter?

---

I did a little research and I couldn't find much but an incomplete wikipedia article (and a few blogs studying this subject from *physics* perspective) stating the following:

> By the 1940s, the science of topology had developed and studied a thorough basic theory of topological spaces of positive dimension. Motivated by computations, and to some extent aesthetics, topologists searched for mathematical frameworks that extended our notion of space to allow for negative dimensions. Such dimensions, as well as the fourth and higher dimensions, are hard to imagine since we are not able to directly observe them. It wasn’t until the 1960s that a special topological framework was constructed—the category of spectra.
> $\quad\quad$— Luke Wolcott, "Imagining Negative-Dimensional Space", Proceedings of Bridges 2012: Mathematics, Music, Art, Architecture, Culture (2012)

---

Comment: Dimensions satisfy $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n\approx\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. So for a negative dimension, $\mathbb{R}^{-1}\times\mathbb{R}\approx\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$. This goes against the current meaning of the $\times$ operation of sets.

Comment: Spectra.... I have heard that the notion hasn't been stabilized yet

Comment: @Chrystomath Obviously such a space would not be a topological space in the traditional sense, and the corresponding product may be very different.

Comment: Usually, I have no problems with generalizing mathematical concepts, but this idea is so weird, that I would not waste my time with such objects even if someone could actually work out a generalization that is consistent with the $n$-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @CaptainLama But it must reduce to the usual product on 'some' spaces, the positive dimensional ones, so it can't be that different either. That's also why I wrote "current".

Comment: @Peter The weirder, the better

Comment: @Veriun In recreational mathematics, people can study such things (if they actually wanto to do it), but this philosophy ("The weirder, the better") can cause immense damage , as moderny physics shows. In particular , the cosmology is in a serious crisis because instead of correcting fallacies , they are cemented with new postulates just to preserve them. Because of this, I disagree.

Comment: The thing is, this all depends on what you accept as a generalization, and what notion of dimension you find interesting. It is quite clear you won't find spaces that have negative dimension "on the nose". But there are such things as negative spheres for instance (where you formally invert sphere spectra in an appropriate monoidal category). And I know that in noncommutative geometry there is a point of view in which the dimension of an object is related to the growth rate of the Laplacian spectrum, so it makes sense to speak about negative dimensions.

Comment: Negative dimensions and imaginary dimensions are very useful.  Stepping into  a negative dimension is a practical way of disappearing while imaginary dimensions, such as dream worlds, heaven or nirvana, have been used for generations.  The dimensionof a nightmare is -i times the days you've remembered it.

Comment: The volume of a unit ball in $n$-dimensional space is $\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(n/2+1)$. Since $\Gamma(z)$ has poles at the non-positive integers, one might make the strange conclusion that the unit ball has volume $0$ in each negative even dimension, but non-zero (and sometimes negative) volume in each negative odd dimension..

Comment: $\emptyset$ satisfies most properties you would expect of a space of dimension $-\infty$.